# Using an API to build a QR Code Generator

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, qr-code

I've been working on a QR Code Generator that uses [this](http://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/) API. For some reason, I'm not able to figure out what's wrong with it. Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sharanisalive/s4z5http/) to see it in a JSFiddle.

HTML:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter text here">
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
<!-- This image should display the QR Code. -->
<img id="resultImage" src="" alt="">
```

JavaScript:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('textInput');
var button = document.getElementById('submitButton');
var image = document.getElementById('resultImage');
button.onclick = function() {
    var resultValue = "http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" + input.value;
    image.setAttribute("src", resultValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return false;` at the end of the `onclick` handler, otherwise clicking the button causes the page to refresh before the QR code has time to render (because the button is of type `submit`)

i.e.

```js
button.onclick = function() {
    var resultValue = "http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" + input.value;
    image.setAttribute("src", resultValue);
    return false;
 }
```